# Setup Free Trial for Paid Apps

Tags: ios

For paid apps in iOS, is there a way to setup a free trial period for xx days (offering full functionality). After xx days, the user must purchase the app for continued usage. It's a one-time paid app and not a recurring subscription based app.

How to setup the trial period? How to prompt user for purchasing before continued usage?

Comment: Are you asking how *you* can offer such a trial version, or are you asking how to get a trial of a commercial app?

Comment: how I can offer such a trial version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide any simple support for trial periods for "normal" paid apps.

You would need to setup your app as free with an in-app purchases for the full version of the app.

You would need to implement your app to give the user full functionality for some amount of time and then fall back to some limited level of functionality after that time runs out. If, at some point, the user purchases the upgrade, you give them the full functionality forever.

You can add whatever prompting at first load and during the trial period that you want to remind the use how much time is left and that they can upgrade through the in-app purchase.

Receipt validation can be used to keep a user from deleting and reinstalling the app to "reset" the trial period. You can get the original "purchase" (download) date from the receipt.

It's a shame that Apple doesn't allow normal trial periods for non-subscription based paid apps.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy!  What kind of in app purchase do you setup for purchasing after trial expires? Also, I am assuming the receipt validation, you would need to implement some kind of server validation?

Comment: No server required to do receipt validation. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573 (though it's dated and in Objective-C). If you want the purchase to be a one-time purchase then use a non-consumable product.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this with in-app purchases, although it is not ideal, because a person can delete the app and install from scratch.

One trick is to insert some special value flagging a trial start in the keychain. This is not deleted automatically between app reinstalls.